# php multi-dimensional array provides three levels of depth instead of two

Tags: php, arrays

When I execute the code below:
[Code](http://ideone.com/8BEEJc):

```
<?php

$data = array();
$jim = array('Jim'=>1);
$bob = array('Bob'=>1);
$data['abc'][] = $jim;
$data['abc'][] = $bob;

print_r($data);
?>
```

I receive the following output:

```
    Array
(
    [abc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Jim] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Bob] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

What I am expecting is the following output:

```
   Array
(
    [abc] => Array
        (
            [Jim] => 1
            [Bob] => 1
        )

)
```

How can I achieve this?  To rephrase the question, how can I keep it to a single sub-array per a supplied key?

Comment: Jim and Bob are arrays by your own declaration, you have to change them first

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ mayor bee.  But Glavic supplied a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating array (`$data['abc']`) which contains an array (`[]`) of arrays(`$jim`, `$bob`)
It's the same as writing:

```
$data['abc'][0] = array('jim' => 1);
$data['abc'][1] = array('bob' => 1);
```

What you want is probably:

```
$data['abc'] = array();
$data['abc'] = array_merge($data['abc'], $jim, $bob);
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is the output I am expecting.  I will change my original question to mirror.  Side note you have `mege` it should be `merge`

Answer (score 5):

```
$data = array();
$jim = array('Jim'=>1);
$bob = array('Bob'=>1);
$data['abc'] = array_merge($jim, $bob);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: Still this will produce 3 levels

Comment: @Darhazer That's what the OP required

Comment: His title kinda contradicts his question. He can just remove the `[]` if he wants to keep it at two levels.

Comment: I have updated my original question because Darhazer provided the output I was expecting.

Comment: You have to understand the problem, not the question, otherwise you fall in the trap of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Jim and Bob are array indexes by your own declaration, you have to change them first

```
<?php

$data = array();
$data['abc']["Jim"] =1;
$data['abc']["Bob"] = 2;

print_r($data);
?>
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/T5Ihy8cH)**